NDSolve to solve a system of ODEs numerically

I am trying to solve and I added a range for each of the variables, but I am still running into problems. Thank you.

Please provide Mathematica code, thanks

You will want to start with a fresh kernel.  The error message says the ICs and BCs have evaluated to "True".  This can happen when we inadvertently evaluate something like x[0] = 1 then change it to x[0] == 1.
